# Unable to login from another wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

My A site passes POST data to site B thus must log in the user into site B.

I prefer not to verify password in site B, so I'm using below:

```
$user = $_POST;

$a = get_user_by('login', $user['data']['user_login']);

do_action('wp_login', $a->data->user_login, $a);
wp_set_current_user( $a->data->ID );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $a->data->ID );
```

I can get current logged in user like this: `wp_get_current_user();`.
also when I check `is_user_logged_in()`, it says true as well. 
But when I redirect to site B, the user is not logged in.

One more is that,

when i echo `site_url()` it says site B url which is correct. BUt when I use `wp_safe_redirect` or `wp_redirect()` it goes to site A.
so I use a hack like this:

```
$string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$string .= 'window.location = "' . site_url() . '"';
$string .= '</script>';

echo $string;
exit;
```

What am I doing wrongly here?

Comment: does `wp_get_current_user()` return the good user ?

Comment: @mmm yes, it returns the correct user